# Dynamic 2D Ogre3D Texutre

Tags: c++, objective-c, ipad, 3d, ogre

I'm trying to create a 2D background for my ogre scene that renders the camera frames for the QCAR SDK. This is on an iPad with iOS 6.

At the moment I'm retrieving the pixel data like so in renderFrameQCAR:

```
const QCAR::Image *image = camFrame.getImage(1);

if(image) {
    pixels = (unsigned char *)image->getPixels();
}
```

This returns pixels in the RGB888 format, then passing it to my ogre scene in the renderOgre() functions:

```
if(isUpdated)
     scene.setCameraFrame(pixels);
scene.m_pRoot->renderOneFrame();
```

The setCameraFrame(pixels) function consists of:

```
void CarScene::setCameraFrame(const unsigned char *pixels)
{
    HardwarePixelBufferSharedPtr pBuffer = m_pBackgroundTexture->getBuffer();

    pBuffer->lock(HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD);
    const PixelBox& pBox = pBuffer->getCurrentLock();

    PixelBox *tmp = new PixelBox(screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, PF_R8G8B8, &pixels);
    pBuffer->blit(pBuffer, *tmp, pBox);
    pBuffer->unlock();

    delete tmp;
}
```

In this function I'm attempting to create a new PixelBox, copy the pixels into it and the copy that over the the pixelBuffer.

When I first create my Ogre3D scene, I set up the m_pBackgroundTexture & background rect2d like so:

```
void CarScene::createBackground()
{
    m_pBackgroundTexture = TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual("DynamicTexture", ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, TEX_TYPE_2D, m_pViewport->getActualWidth(), m_pViewport->getActualHeight(), 0, PF_R8G8B8, TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE);

    m_pBackgroundMaterial = MaterialManager::getSingleton().create("Background", ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);

    m_pBackgroundMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->createTextureUnitState("DynamicTexture");
    m_pBackgroundMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setSceneBlending(SBT_TRANSPARENT_ALPHA);
    m_pBackgroundMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setDepthCheckEnabled(false);
    m_pBackgroundMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setDepthWriteEnabled(false);
    m_pBackgroundMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setLightingEnabled(false);

    m_pBackgroundRect = new Rectangle2D(true);

    m_pBackgroundRect->setCorners(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    m_pBackgroundRect->setMaterial("Background");
    m_pBackgroundRect->setRenderQueueGroup(RENDER_QUEUE_BACKGROUND);

    AxisAlignedBox aabInf;
    aabInf.setInfinite();

    m_pBackgroundRect->setBoundingBox(aabInf);

    SceneNode* node = m_pSceneManager->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    node->attachObject(m_pBackgroundRect);
```

}

After this all I get is a white background with no texture, and I have no idea why this is not displaying the output! My goal for this is just to have the camera rendering in the background so I can project my 3d model onto it.

Thanks,
Harry.

Comment: Are you sure renderFrameQCAR is working? You seem to be debugging both the render system and the pixel source at the same time. Does the dynamic texture work if you just provide it with dummy pixel data?